# computer restarted if I have power off the monitor only

Tags: windows-xp, display, reboot

I have installed windows XP 32 bit with intel quad core process and 2GB of RAM. From last few months I have noticed wired behavior of my system. During the work if I am off the monitor noly (not CPU) and again ON it then the system get restarted automatically. Don't know what is the problem. ( I have 14' CRT monitor)

Comment: Considering the sheer age of any crt monitor, I wonder if we have a short circuit somewhere. Can you test it with another monitor?

Comment: Thanks for the coment. No I don't think this is the problem. and no I do not test it with another monitor

Comment: Replace the monitor, it is most likely causing a mains spike when powered off/on. The other option is to get a UPS or a mains adapter that includes a mains filter for the PC.

Comment: In order to see if the monitor is truly causing the issue, connect the computer to another monitor. If the problem does not exist, purchase a new monitor.

Comment: Is there anything happening if there is no cable connected between computer and monitor? You should try it: power up computer and monitor `=>` disconnect monitor from computer `=>` power off monitor `=>` see if anything happens.

Comment: @Sampo I will try and update here, thanks for suggestion